# Strange CMake shared lib linking issue on Linux

Tags: objective-c, linux, linker, cmake, objective-c++

I'm seeing a weird linking issue on Linux with a cross-platform library project that uses CMake to create both an OS X Framework and a Linux shared library from the same source tree. The cross-platform aspect of that project has worked well in the past (up to about two years ago), but since then, we have exclusively done development work on OS X. The reason for the temporary Linux abandonment was a developer shortage: all those who remained used OS X - there was no technical reason for not building the source on Linux for some years.

And with one potentially relevant exception (more on this later), there have been no fundamental changes to our source in the meantime. But of course Linux has advanced: so of course there were some minor snags at first when we went back there. Things like the new version of the compiler complaining about things they had not complained about in the past (questionable casts, void pointer voodoo, and such). These issues were resolved in short order.

The entire source tree now compiles again on Mint 17.1 with some definitely harmless remaining warnings. But linking fails with a rather bizarre message:

```
Linking CXX shared library lib<ourLibName>.so
CMakeFiles/<file1>.c.o:1:1: error: stray '\177' in program
CMakeFiles/<file1>.c.o:1:1: error: stray '\2' in program
CMakeFiles/<file2>.c.o:1:1: error: stray '\213' in program
(and so on, thousands of times, with seemingly random values in the quotes
for all the object files in the library)
```

To me, this looks like the linker is accidentally trying to *compile* the object files one more time, instead of linking them. Switching between gcc and clang made no difference.

As I already said, there was one potentially relevant structural change to the project since it last compiled under Linux: it used to be a combination of only C and Objective-C sources. It now contains C, Objective-C ***as well as Objective-C++*** source. On OS X, this change has not caused any issues whatsoever, and it is very hard for me to imagine that this addition of some .mm files is causing what we are seeing here. But still - weirder things have happened.

Also, there is a popular issue with several articles on stackoverflow about erroneously including unicode characters in C/C++ programs. This is not the problem here - no such messages appear during the actual compilation. The circus only starts once linking should happen.

The source tree is far too large to post, and the CMake files are also fairly involved, nested, and large (i.e. impossible to include here). To add insult to injury, they have worked fine in the past, on Ubuntu 10.10. Which I don't have around anymore, to test if the current tree still works there (that would have been far too easy, I guess). The relevant commands in the CMakeList that generate the library under Linux are

```
set_target_properties(
    <ourLibName> 
    PROPERTIES
        VERSION    2.0
        SOVERSION  2
    )

target_link_libraries(
    <ourLibName>
    ${our_other_link_libraries}
    )

install (
    TARGETS
        <ourLibName>
    DESTINATION
        lib
    )
```

which still looks o.k. to me at first glance. How do I proceed here? I'm out of ideas on what to try next.

P.S. versions of the software involved: Cmake 2.8.11, gcc 4.8.2, clang 3.4-1ubuntu3.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the root of the problem was simple: one of the project devs who is no longer with us had apparently made an attempt to build the Objective-C++ version of the source on Linux, a year or two ago. From his abortive attempt, there was a sensible-looking leftover in the Linux-only part of the CMake compiler flags:

```
else ( APPLE )
    set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -x objective-c++" )
endif ( APPLE )
```

The kicker is of course the `-x objective-c++` flag. That does not cause any harm during compilation, except that you get tons of unnecessary warnings. But as these flags are *also passed to the linker*, it forces the poor thing into treating all the object files as ObjC++ input. That flag should never have been there: CMake is smart enough to handle a mixture of C, ObjC and ObjC++ right out of the box. Once the flag is removed, everything works as expected.